Convergence or divergence of the integral $\int_0^{\infty} x \sin (x^3) dx$
I received as a homework assignment to show the following integral:
$\int_0^{\infty} x \cdot \sin (x^3) dx$
either converges/ absolutely converges/ diverges.
I will say in advance, we have just started defining improper integrals, and we've covered the two basic convergence tests: comparison tests, and the limit comparison test. Additionally we proved the Dirichlet test. Therefore we are expected to use these tools, and not something more advanced.
I tried using the tests to try and prove the integral absolutely converges (since the given integrand is not a non-negative function), but I couldn't succeed. I've tried other methods, such as substitution, but again, I got stuck at some point.
Any suggestions on a first, or a few first steps for how to proceed would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

One possible difference might be the avoidance of the Dirichlet test in the referred answer. Substitute, then test using Dirichlet's, and done.

Detailed explanation has been put on the redirected post.
